# Удалить строку в массиве через указатель Си

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, null

Необходимо удалить из массива строку, в которой заданная буква встречается наибольшее количество раз.
Проблема заключается в удалении строки по указателю. То есть, при присвоении строке NULL и при дальнейшем ее выводе через указатель, она не выводится. А при выводе массива целиком, она выводится, словно с ней ничего  и не произошло. Вопрос - что тогда меняется по указателю?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define N 80 
#define M 5 

void main(void){ 
    char *abc[M]={"do you", "know de way", "my ugandian warrior", "just follow me", "in aarmy of ugaanda"},*p,**str,**cur,letter; 
    int i=0,buf=0,max=0; 
    str=abc; 
    while(i<M){ 
       puts(*str); 
       str++; 
       i++; 
   } 
   printf("Enter the letter: "); 
   scanf("%c", &letter); 
   i=0; 
   for(i=0;i<M;i++){ 
      p=abc[i]; 
      do{ 
         if(*p==letter) buf++; 
         p++; 
      }while(*p!='\0'); 
      if(buf>max){ 
         p=abc[i]; 
         max=buf; 
         cur=&p; 
         buf=0; 
      } 
      buf=0; 
   } 
   *cur=NULL; 
   str=abc; 
   i=0; 
   while(i<M){ 
      puts(*str); 
      str++; 
       i++; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы отформатируйте код, смотрится вырвиглазно.

Comment: @MrBin отформатировал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше

```
cur = &p;
...
*cur = NULL;
```

обнуляет лишь какую-то локальную переменную `p`. На массив `abc` это обнуление никакого воздействия не оказывает. Потому вы и не видите никаких изменений в массиве `abc`.

Когда вы искали строку, вам надо было делать

```
cur = &abc[i];
```

а не какое-то непонятно зачем нужное `cur = &p;`.

---

Однако передавать нулевой указатель напрямую в `puts` нельзя - поведение не определено. Все просто упадет. Некоторые реализации может быть и заметят это и напечатают что-нибудь вроде `(null)`, но это не повод так поступать.

Comment: Честно говоря, я по итогу сделал проще - просто избавился от указателя первого порядка, оставив только второй.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, разбираться в мельтешении вашего кода откровенно лень :) Если это то, о чём я думаю (то есть просто обнулить указатель на строку в исходном массиве), то как-то так, например:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */
static size_t chars_count( const char *string, char c )
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while( string && *string ) {
        if( *string == c )
            ++count;
        ++string;
    }
    return count;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */
static int del_strings( char *data[], size_t data_size, char c, size_t n )
{
    int removed = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < data_size; ++i ) {
        size_t count = chars_count( data[i], c );
        if( count >= n ) {
            ++removed;
            data[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return removed;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */
static void print_strings( const char *prefix, char *data[], size_t data_size )
{
    printf( "%s:\n", prefix );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < data_size; ++i ) {
        printf( "[%zu] %s\n", i, data[i] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */
int main( void )
{
    char *abc[] = { "do you", "know de way", "my ugandian warrior",
                    "just follow me", "in aarmy of ugaanda" };
#define ABC_SIZE (sizeof(abc) / sizeof(abc[0]))
    int rc;
    print_strings( "Before", abc, ABC_SIZE );
    rc = del_strings( abc, ABC_SIZE, 'a', 2 );
    print_strings( "After", abc, ABC_SIZE );
    return rc;
}
```

Но имейте в виду, что это потенциально опасный подход.